# how to filter the data of QComboBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a tableWidget in each row I insert a combobox that have the same data source I want that when the user selects an item from a combobox it will not find in other combobox

Comment: The question is hard to understand, could you post some code and the expected result?

Comment: I have a table that contains for example the following data 
T = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"] 
the user will select "BB" in the first combobox, then the 2 nd combobox has the right to choose only between "AA", "CC", "DD" so on .. but it is possible to modify each combobox at any time

Answer (score 1):

I hope C++ syntax is familiar to you.

1. Create one item model (for alll comboboxes) with your data for QComboBox (for example, based on `QStandardItemModel`)
2. Declare a custom user role (`const int ComboIdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;`). It will keep our "ID" of combobox, where item is selected.
3. Create custom filter model (based on `QSortFilterProxyModel`), where you will keep "ComboID" and reimplement `filterAcceptsRow` method:

> ```
> const int ComboIdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;
>
> class ComboProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
> {
>   //...
> public:
>   ComboProxyModel( QComboBox *view )
>     : QSortFilterProxyModel( view )
>   {
>     m_id = (quint64)view; // Or any id, must be uniqe for each combobox
>   }
>
> private:
>   quint64 m_id;
>
>   bool filterAcceptsRow( int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent )
>   {
>     const QModelIndex idx = source_parent.child( source_row, 0 );
>     const quint64 itemId = idx.data( ComboIdRole ).toULongLong();
>     if ( itemId != 0 )
>     {
>       if ( itemId != m_id ) // Do not accept if item is already selected
>         return false;       // and skip current combobox
>     }
>
>     return true;
>   }
> };
> ```

1. Create 1 filtering model per QComboBox. And set this model as source to combobox.
2. On selection change signal you should set to a selected item necessary role. And don't forget to set 0 to unselected item.
3. Profit!

Main concept - use Qt MVC (model + filteringModel) and set it as source model to QComboBox

P.S. stackoverflow formatting is to buggy :(

Comment: @HaussemChƏdly if you want a python code - write it. If something is unclear - ask it. I don't want to implement something instead of you, because it breaks stackoverflow conception.